# What is the difference of meaning between these 2 sentences

Tags: meaning

I know I can write this
"I had been staying for 3 days in Paris when it happened "or that "I was staying for 3 days when it happened"
does it mean that in the second sentence my staying continued after the event happened. It was not completed as in the first sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an oddity of English (that often causes misunderstanding for speakers of other languages) that *for (a time)* with a present tense looks forward, while *for (a time)* with a perfect construction looks backward.

> How long are you [staying] in Paris? I'm [staying] here for two weeks.

This is a question about the end of your visit (whether "staying" is in there or not). It can sometimes be ambiguous - the answer could mean "until two weeks from now" or "until two weeks after I arrived".

Contrast this with

> How long have you been [staying] in Paris?

This question is unambiguously "How long is it since you arrived", and a native speaker would answer "I've been here for two weeks", not "I am here for two weeks", which answers the different question I discussed above.

So, though it is less clear-cut, your suggestion is correct about your two sentences. The first one, with *had been* is definitely as you suggest.

The second one, *I was staying for three days* is a bit confusing, and I don't think native speakers would be likely to say it for that reason; but the most likely interpretation is "I was at some unspecified point in a three-day stay when it happened".

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 says that it happened after you had been staying for three days in Paris. It is not clear whether you intended to stay longer.

Sentence 2 says that it was during a three-day stay in Paris that it happened. It is not clear from this sentence at what stage of your visit that it occurred.

Comment: if I change in the second sentence when by before"I was staying for 3 days before it happened  does it now mean the same as the first one